# Nuxt ignores use own plugin

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I tried to install plugin, but nothing happened.
**Install method is called.**

P.S. It's just example function in plugin.

nuxt.config.js:

```
...
export default {
  ...
  plugins: [ '~/plugins/myplugin' ],
  ...
}
...
```

myplugin file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.use({
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$a = (...data) => { console.log(...data); };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to call my example plugin, and it works, but property `this.$a` was hidden.

But if you want to correctly registration: in some module, i found this registration, and it works!

```
Vue.use({
  install(Vue, options = {}) {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$a', {
      get() {
        return (...data) => console.log(...data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the add ‘.js’ to your reference in the plugins key.

```
plugins: [ '~/plugins/myplugin.js ' ],
```

Comment: No, cause "install" method is called